# Rejected edit that updates outdated information

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I had my first rejected today; I tried to updated some out of date and incorrect information here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7224731. This was an attempt to bring the answer in line with [Avoid stepping through javascript file in Chrome Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7827882), which is not out of date.

Could someone please explain why my edit was rejected? I am not upset; I am genuinely curious how I should go about updating answers which are no longer correct.

Comment: That probably should have been a new answer and/or a comment saying that it's outdated.